# c++ matrix class different dimensions

Tags: c++

```
template <int rows, int cols>
class Matrix{
 std::array<double, rows*cols> mData;
...
}
```

What's the right way to define `operator*` to be able to multiply matrices which don't have same dimensions?

I tried this but it obviously doesn't work as it expects same dimensions.

```
template <int rows, int cols>
Matrix<rows,cols> operator*(Matrix<rows,cols>& a, Matrix<rows,cols>& b){...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a third template argument:

```
template <int N, int M, int P>
Matrix<N,P> operator*(Matrix<N,M>& a, Matrix<M,P>& b)
{
    ...
}
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 3):

You need three parameters:

```
template <int rows, int cols, int cols2>
Matrix<rows,cols2> operator*(Matrix<rows,cols>& a, Matrix<cols,cols2>& b){...}
```